# Assign additional attributes to types like int, float for reflection purposes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I am trying to automate the display (gathering via reflection) of my variables which are located in specific scripts in Unity. The trouble is assigning custom values (for example: "string DisplayName", "bool DisplayMe", "bool WriteMe" etc.). When it comes to my custom classes I understand how I would do it, but I would like to avoid remaking types like float, string, int etc. for this purpose.

For example, let's say I have:

```
public class myBaseClass
{
    public string Name = "Display Name";
    public bool AmReadable = true;
    public bool AmWritable = true;
}
```

Then:

```
public class myDoubleFloat: myBaseClass
{
    public float ValueFirst;
    public float ValueSecond;
}
```

So in some scripts in Unity I define it:

```
public class SomeScriptOnGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public myDoubleFloat myFirstVariable{get; set;}
    public float mySecondVariable{get; set;}
}
```

So later on with reflection I can check whether "myFirstVariable" should be read, it's display name etc. - while for "mySecondVariable" I cannot perform this check. How do I go about this without reinventing the wheel and making a class for each of these types like float, string, int, List etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping value objects (`int`, `float`, etc.) is probably not the best approach.  Besides the additional complexity (and possibility for bugs), you are now bloating the memory footprint of your game.

(I'm intentionally avoiding newer C# syntax in these examples)

Since you are already in a reflection context, instead of wrapping your value objects, I'd suggest an attribute-based approach.  For example:

```
public class SomeScriptOnGameObject
{
    [DisplayName("First Variable"), Writable]
    public float FirstVariable { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Second Variable")]
    public float SecondVariable { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Some Field")]
    public float Field;

    public float FieldWithNoAttributes;
}
```

This has the advantage of keeping the metadata of the fields in the metadata, instead of carrying around a copy of everything with every instance you create.

The actual attributes are easy to create, also.  I'll start with the simplest one, `WritableAttribute`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class WritableAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

This empty class is all that's needed to mark a field or property as "Writable".  The `AttributeUsage` marks this as only valid on fields and properties (not, for example, a class).

The other attribute, `DisplayName`, is only slightly more complex:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public sealed class DisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }

    public DisplayNameAttribute(string displayName)
    {
        DisplayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

The main difference is the constructor with the `displayName` argument, and the `DisplayName` property.  This forces the compiler to expect an argument to the attribute.

With some extension methods, you can make things very clean:

```
public static class AttributeExtensions
{
    public static bool IsWritable(this MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        return memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(WritableAttribute)).Any();
    }

    public static string DisplayName(this MemberInfo memberInfo)
    {
        var displayNameAttribute =
            memberInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute))
                .FirstOrDefault() as DisplayNameAttribute;
        return displayNameAttribute == null ? null : displayNameAttribute.DisplayName;
    }

    public static PropertyInfo Property<T>(this T _, string propertyName)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    }

    public static FieldInfo Field<T>(this T _, string fieldName)
    {
        return typeof(T).GetField(fieldName);
    }
}
```

(Since you mentioned you are already using reflection, you might not need the last two methods there.)

Finally, a simple XUnit test to demonstrate:

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var obj = new SomeScriptOnGameObject();

        Assert.True(obj.Property("FirstVariable").IsWritable());
        Assert.False(obj.Property("SecondVariable").IsWritable());
        Assert.False(obj.Field("Field").IsWritable());

        Assert.Equal("First Variable", obj.Property("FirstVariable").DisplayName());
        Assert.Equal("Second Variable", obj.Property("SecondVariable").DisplayName());
        Assert.Equal("Some Field", obj.Field("Field").DisplayName());

        Assert.Null(obj.Field("FieldWithNoAttributes").DisplayName());
    }
}
```

Comment: This stuff is amazing, where was this all my life? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can define a generic wrapper:

```
public class MyProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public T Get() => _value;

    public T Set(T newValue) => _value = newValue;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool AmReadable { get; set; }

    public bool AmWritable { get; set; }
}
```

And make your properties's getters and setter to map to some backing fields of type `MyProperty<T>`:

```
public class SomeScriptOnGameObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private MyProperty<MyDoubleFloat> _myFirstVariable;

    private MyProperty<float> _mySecondVariable;

    public MyDoubleFloat MyFirstVariable
    {
        get => _myFirstVariable.Get();
        set => _myFirstVariable.Set(value);
    }

    public float MySecondVariable
    {
        get => _mySecondVariable.Get();
        set => _mySecondVariable.Set(value);
    }

    public SomeScriptOnGameObject()
    {
        _myFirstVariable = new MyProperty<MyDoubleFloat>
        {
            //configuration
        };

        _mySecondVariable = new MyProperty<float>
        {
            //configuration
        };
    }
}
```

If you want to be fancy you can even add an implicit operator to get rid of `Get()` and make any `T` assignable from `MyProperty<T>`:

```
    public class MyProperty<T>
    {
        private T _value;

        public T Set(T newValue) => _value = newValue;

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool AmReadable { get; set; }

        public bool AmWritable { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator T(MyProperty<T> myProperty) => 
            myProperty != null ? myProperty._value : default;
    }
```

And:

```
  public MyDoubleFloat MyFirstVariable
    {
        get => _myFirstVariable;
        set => _myFirstVariable.Set(value);
    }
```

Comment: Didn't work with wrappers yet, so it 's like voodoo to me atm. Will test it out right now but if it works like I imagine it does, it will be exactly what I need.

Comment: Another question though: Let's say I get the value of this reflection via GetValue and name it myTestDoubleFloat. When I do myTestDoubleFloat.ValueFirst it returns as it should - how do I get "AmReadable", "AmWritable", "Name" from it? Because it returns "Type MyDoubleFloat does not contain definition for ..."

Comment: You have to inspect the backing field of type `MyProperty<T>`. Either do that or make your main propery myTestDoubleFloat of type `MyProperty<T>` since it is the wrapper which holds all that metadata.

Comment: Care to point me at how to get your first described variant from a property? In short, I do: System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties(); ("this" being script attached to a GameObject containing these variables I'm searching for). Then I do for (on "properties" array) - Let's say properties[0] is myFirstVariable (or alternatively that testMyFirstVariable is GetValue of properties[0]) - how do I get form either of these two to getting "Name" or "AmReadable" (etc.) from it's MyProperty<T> of that variable?